# What is the significance of set_serial option while generating client certificate?

Tags: haproxy

What is the significance of set_serial option while generating client certificate.

```
# client certificate creation
openssl genrsa -out client1.key 1024
openssl genrsa -out client2.key 1024
openssl req -new -key client1.key -out client1.csr
openssl req -new -key client2.key -out client2.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client1.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client1.crt
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in client2.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out client2.crt
```

I used same serial number 01 for all client certificates. Is there any issue when revoke a specific client certificate ?

Comment: I want to know the answer to this as well!

Answer (score 5):

The serial number becomes part of the certificate and can be used by the certificate authority to ID the signed certificates.

Answer (score 5):

Each certificate is uniquely identified by a serial number and so needed when generating the certificate. When issuing a certificate, CA has to make sure that the serial number is unique and not reused.

When a certificate is revoked/expired, a new certificate is issued, only difference between the old and new certificate will be just the serial number. Since no other data in the certificate can uniquely identify a certificate within a CA, serial number is needed. There can be two certificates for the same site/domain with only difference being the serial number. Serial number uniquely identifies a certificate within the CA.

Answer (score 5):

[CA/Browser forum](https://cabforum.org/2016/03/31/ballot-164/) recommends not to use subsequent serial numbers in TLS certificates anymore:

> Effective September 30, 2016, CAs SHALL generate Certificate serial numbers greater than zero (0) containing at least 64 bits of output from a CSPRNG

So you can use the new [-rand_serial](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-ca.html) option, recently added to openssl.

And if that option is not available, you can use the workaround:

```
openssl x509 ... -set_serial "0x`openssl rand -hex 8`"
```

Comment: Why are consecutive serial numbers no longer recommended? Was there a security issue?